# Git: Manually edit diff of whole file for selective staging?

Tags: git

I often use `git add --patch` in order to stage only select changes to a file; but sometimes, I have a file where the changes I want to stage are very mixed with the changes I don't want to stage. I've been using the feature of manually editing a diff hunk before staging it, but it can get a bit annoying to edit each hunk one at a time. Is there a way to manually edit a diff of the whole file and then stage it instead of each individual hunk?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run `git diff` with whatever options you like (e.g., the specific file in question), redirect the output to a file, edit the file, and run `git apply --cached --recount` on the patch file.  Note that this is different from `git apply --index`, which tries to patch both the working tree file *and* the index copy.

Personally, I don't like to do this sort of thing.  Instead, I just move the file out of the way (e.g., foo.c becomes foo.c+), restore the current index copy, edit that in my editor until I have the one I want to have in the index, and then `git add` that one.  After committing, I can then `mv foo.c+ foo.c`.  The issue I have here is that the index copy is not easily visible, and I like to see exactly what I am going to commit, rather than shadows of differences between what I am going to commit, and what I have in my working tree.

Comment: I get a `corrupt patch` error when I try to run `git apply --cached` on the edited file.

Comment: I forgot to mention that you'll want `--recount` if you don't adjust the patch counts. The `add -p` code uses `--recount` when it runs `git apply --cached`.

Comment: Yes, those are the counts that `--recount` says to recompute instead of trusting :-)

Comment: Thank you! That worked. This is exactly what I wanted.